# How to refresh ui-grid cell which has a cellFilter to display multiple fields of the bound entity in one cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I use a cell filter to show multiple properties of a bound entity in one cell. Therefore there is no one field name because it is a computed field. How can I force the grid to reevaluate the cell filter if one of the involved properties changes?

The column definition:

```
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'xxx', displayName: 'Something', cellFilter: 'concatSomeProps:this' }
]
```

The filter:

```
myApp.filter('concatSomeProps', function () {
  return function (cellValue, scope) {
    var entity = scope.row.entity;
    return entity.prop1 + ", " + entity.prop2;
  };
});
```

If have tried to use notifyDataChanged or the refresh function of the grid api but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a `cellTemplate`, and not a filter in this case:

```
{ field: 'xxx', displayName: 'Something', cellTemplate:'template.html' }
```

And

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
   <div>
       {{row.entity.name + row.entity.age}}
   </div>
</script>
```

[See this Plnkr I made for you to see what I'm talking about](https://plnkr.co/edit/CoPltV9uLawGKHAHnR5W?p=preview). Edit either one of the first two fields and you will see the concat field change. You'd also change your template to use `row.entity.prop1` + `row.entity.prop2` to make it work, as my template is for my columns.